# Show that $\dfrac{1}{1 + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i} \geq \dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_i 1+a_i} \geq \prod\limits_i\dfrac{1}{1+a_i}$

Tags: inequality

I wish to show that given a finite set of nonnegative numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$

$\dfrac{1}{1 + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i} \geq \dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_i 1+a_i} \geq \prod\limits_i\dfrac{1}{1+a_i}$

using well known facts about inequality.

I recognize that the first one can be established by knowing that $1 + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i \leq \prod\limits_i 1+a_i$, can someone help me with establishing the second inequality?

Comment: Aren't the second and third term *equal?*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to think.

Comment: Is there a particular name to the fact $1 + \sum\limits_i^n a_i \leq \prod_i 1+a_i$?

Comment: I don't know, but it can easily be shown by induction of by expanding the terms of the product. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003343/multiplicative-sum-is-bigger-than-sum-prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_i 1+a_i} =\prod\limits_i\dfrac{1}{1+a_i}$ !!

Answer (score 1):

We prove $1+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i) $ by induction:

For n=1:
$1+a_1=1+a_1$

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Let's asume $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \prod_i(1+a_i) $ holds for some n.

**Inductive Step:** 
$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1+a_i)=(1+a_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\geq(1+a_{n+1})(1+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)=1+a_{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ ...

Since $ a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^na_i \ge 0$ it follows:

...
$\ge 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i $